# QLPreviewController VS UIWebView in terms of render efficience and memory usage

Tags: ios, uiwebview, doc, quicklook, qlpreviewcontroller

I am working on an iPad project which lets users browse local docs, ppts, pdfs and etc..

I have two options to display these files:

First, I can use UIWebView to display them;

Alternatively, I can use QLPreviewController to display them.

From ActivityConsole, I figure out that when I use UIWebView to display a 8.6M PPT, my app's process costs as following:

[image: My App's process cost]

However, when I use QLPreviewController to display the same PPT, there will be two process as following:

[image: My App's process and quicklook process]

I think the "quicklookd" process is a helper process launched by the QuickLook Framework.

As I see, the overall memory usage is about the same, but using QLPreviewController can cut down the memory usage of my App ( It is proved in Instruments ). So I think the display of doc can be more smooth and fast by using QLPreviewController. However, when I test these two approches in iPad1, iOS 5.1.1, I found out that the render effcience of QLPreviewController is lower than UIWebView. The scrolling of the ppt chokes much more in QLPreviewController.

Can anyone explain the underlying implement of QLPreviewController render process? And which is the better choice to display docs?

Or is there a better approach to display docs except above approches?

Thank you for any help!